# Laravel 5.4 - How to route with wildcard?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

After some playing around and research it seems that `Route::when()` and `Route::filter()` are deprecated in Laravel 5+. I need to be able to route all URIs that begin with `members` to the same controller. For example:

```
Route::get('members/home', 'MembersController');
Route::get('members/view/all', 'MembersController');
Route::get('members/any/possible/route', 'MembersController');
```

I will not know all the possible routes that begin with members, as they will be stored in my database. Is there a wildcard equivalent to what Laravel 4.2 had that I can use in 5.4?

The idea is to have any routes that begin with certain prefixes to go to its specified controller, then the controller will compare the entire URI string and retrieve the page that has the matching slug in the db.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this using a route parameter that allows any value. E.g. `(.*)`. You'll then need to handle all of the requests from a single controller action.

```
Route::get('members/{action}', 'MemberController@all')->where('action', '(.*)');
```

To take this further, if you don't know that your requests will all be `GET` requests, you could use the `:any` method type.

```
Route::any('members/{action}', 'MemberController@all')->where('action', '(.*));
```

Comment: Brilliant! This is exactly what I need. Thank you much!

Comment: Bro getting error in there `Route::resource('questions', 'QuestionController')->parameters(['questions' => 'question_slug'])->where(['slug' => '^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$']);`

Comment: @fubar can you correct your first example in this answer, it should be Route::get('members/{action}', 'MemberController@all')->where('action', '(.*)')

Answer (score 2):

```
Route::get('/members/{section}', 'MembersController@index' )
       ->where(['section' => '.*']);
```

Or better yet you can use a group route. It's faster and optimizes your app.

```
Route::prefix('members')->group(function () {
    Route::get('{section}', 'MembersController@index' )
        ->where(['section' => '.*']);
});
```